# How to write a select case join?

Tags: select, if-statement, join, case

I am trying to some sql code that combines information from 2 tables and uses case but it is not returning all the data.

```
SELECT TABLE1.PRODUCT, TABLE1.TYPE, TABLE1.AMOUNT,
(CASE
  WHEN TABLE1.PRODUCT = 'RADIO'
    THEN 100
  ELSE 200
  END) AS PRODUCT_CODE,
(CASE
  WHEN TABLE1.TYPE = 'NEW'
     THEN 'Y'
  ELSE TABLE2.AGE
  END) AS STATUS
FROM TABLE1 LEFT JOIN TABLE 2 ON TABLE1.TID = TABLE2.TID
WHERE TABLE1.DATE > '01-AUG-15'
AND TABLE2.DATE = '02-AUG-15'
```

The problem I am having is that I need all records from table1 and those that apply from table2 but when the query is returning less rows than there are in table 1.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here

`AND TABLE2.DATE = '02-AUG-15'`

If `Table2.Date` is null due to the left join, this condition fails, which is why you are getting less rows than `Table1`.  Adding a condition to the where clause from a left joined table is effectively turning it into an inner join.

Try either

`AND (TABLE2.DATE = '02-AUG-15' OR TABLE2.DATE IS NULL)`

(this assumes that `TABLE2.DATE` is not nullable) or put the condition in the join statement instead

`FROM TABLE1 LEFT JOIN TABLE 2 ON TABLE1.TID = TABLE2.TID AND TABLE2.DATE = '02-AUG-15'`

Comment: Thanks Paul. the second option putting it in the join statement worked out great!